# Viewing mobile site on desktop

Tags: android, ios, mobile, browser, usability

Is there a browser or program that will enable me to view mobile formats of sites?  I am trying to mimic mobile browsers on a desktop (osx or windows).

I've used user agent switcher on firefox but was wondering if are a browser made for desktop made just to view mobile sites and their source.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

With Chrome click F12 and then click on the phone icon "Toggle device mode"

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode